# How to setup repository for php(yii) project on windows?

Tags: php, yii, repository

We are developing a `CMS` based project in `YII2.0` and using advanced app.

We are having team of 3 guys working on different modules to avoid integration problem we want we should work single project folder.

We trying to setup repository but really no great help over internet. We are using 2 window based system and one `linux` system. While initial development started on window system so, we want it should be root of project code. Rest two system can access both application and project folder. We all are connected through intranet.

Comment: You're using git or svn?

Comment: I have tried both GIT UI and Bazaar but not enough sources available to setup because I am trying to use it first time.

Comment: try installing SourceTree : https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: Can you please, specify documentation for stting it up also the guy working on linux can access it?

Comment: I don't think sourcetree available for linux, but for windows and mac should be fine

Comment: ohh that's the problem becuase on guy is working on linux based system

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://bitbucket.org/ or https://github.com/, so your code will be stored on your Windows as a client and then you can push your code to one of those. Then your Linux guy can pull the code using a git client or using command line. In that way you can use Sourcetree and Linux guy the tool of his preference.

Hope it helps.